# How do I align second row of wrapped cards to the first row with Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox, flex-wrap: wrap.

How do I align second row of wrapped cards to the first row?

This is the current behavior:
[image: Card are not attached to the cards above]

I would like to have the second row of cards top 'connect' to first rows bottom.

The only alternate solution I found was putting it in flex-direction:column, but I don't want the cards extending horizontally (there can be unlimited amount of cards).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post up the html/css you are using.

Comment: Thank you, this is a duplicate, haven't found it when I was searching!